# How do I integrate a fork of one of the crates I'm using into my project?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

One of the external crates I'm using in my project is throwing an error that is not yet fixed in master branch.

However, following [this discussion](https://github.com/actix/actix-extras/issues/176), someone implemented a fork that does fix the error (see last comment by @miraclx).

What would be the right way to for me to integrate their code into my project? And how do I prevent cargo from overwriting it in the future?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to specify a certain commit in dependencies in Cargo.toml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54196846/155423); [How to tell Cargo to use a git repository as source for an indirect dependency instead of crates.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40070903/155423); [How to use a local unpublished crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33025887/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Thanks, the 1st answer does indeed cover it. The rev part was the missing piece in my head.